# Install .Net 2.0 on Windows 10 1809 failed

Tags: windows-10, .net, dism

I have 4 identical computers with fresh install of Windows 10 1809 pro x64 french, workgroup, no antivirus, no WSUS. The first were cloned 3 times, i made a sysprep after each clone.

I want to install a software (don't matted which software is) but block at prerequisite check : *.Net Framework 2.0 not installed*.

I check the checkbox on *Additional features* : "*.Net 2.0 3.0 3.5...*", install using Windows Update, seems success.

After a reboot, the software refuses to install, same reason.

In *Additional features*, .Net2/3/3.5 is now checked. So I uncheck and apply.
I got error 0x80004005. .Net2/3/3.5 still checked.

In *HKLM/Software/Microsoft/.NETFramework/* i have version v2.0.... + v4.0... only, not "v3.0".

In the folder *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64*, it seems all versions are here.

Using *DISM /enable-feature /featurename:Netfx3* (/online, using original ISO...) => success (about 5 sec); but *DISM /disable-feature /featurename:Netfx3* => error 0x80004005, same as GUI. Didn't found relevant info in *DISM.log*.

*SFC /scannow* => no error found

*DISM /checkhealth* => no error found

Using original online or offline setup of .Net 2.0 or 3.5 => Windows 10 ask "*install prerequisites*" or "*ignore*".

- *Install prerequisites* immediately return "*success, may restart the program...*".
- *Ignore* do nothing.

In eventviewer, each time i use DISM command, i get :

- "*System restore*" error 0x80070422
- "*Windows Error Reporting*" information about *CBS Package Servicing failure* on *Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package*, but P6=80004005 : Same error as DISM.

*DISM /get-features* lists a lot of things, *NetFX3 "activated"*, no trace of *Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package*.

Versions:

- Windows: 10.0.17763.437
- DISM: 10.0.17763.1
- CBS(?): 10.0.17763.402

Any help appreciated

Comment: It's likely that the installer isn't checking appropriately for .Net 2.0. Try copying the program from another computer and running it without installing it.

Comment: The program is protected, it's impossible. However i will try to run another app requiring .Net 2.0. I used "Asoft .Net Version Detector", which says 2.0 3.0 3.5 are installed.
That's don't explain why i cannot uninstall .Net 2.0/3.0/3.5.